# JAVA/XML resolving all ref

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, ref

We are consuming a large XML document containing many ref's. Using JAXB we successfully unmarshal the document.  Using a method, we pass nodes to resolve references using a simple ternary operator:

someElement = someElement.getRef() != null ? (someClass)someElement.getRef() : someElement;

We are also required to generate a PDF based on certain child elements. Using JAXB.marshal we output a child node to a string, however the references are not resolved and we are missing content. Furthermore, the above statement, while simple, is executed many times and we'd like to avoid it entirely.

Is there a way to configure JAXB to resolve this references while marshalling? Or any alternative to pre-processing the document?

Input:

```
<Root>
  <Category>
    <SomeElement ref="someId" />
  </Category>
  <SomeElement id="someId">
    <ValuableContent>HelloWorld</ValuableContent>
  </SomeElement>
<Root>
```

Desired:

```
<Root>
  <Category>
    <SomeElement>
      <ValuableContent>HelloWorld</ValuableContent>
    </SomeElement>
  </Category>
<Root>
```

Answer (score 0):

We ended up using XpathFactory to find all elements with a ref attribute, and replaced those with the equivalent element with matching id attribute. There are 2 issues with the solution.

1. Changing the structure of the document causes issues with the XSD validation or unmarshalling. This is not a concern for this effort as we are consuming the data and discarding the refactored xml.
2. It is possible multiple ref's can refer to the same id. Using the replaceChild method for the first match moves the matching id element. The subsequent ref's would require copies or else the original element is moved again.